# shifting elements in an array to the right, returning second largest, removing elements (beginning java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Write array methods that carry out the following tasks for an array of integers by completing the ArrayMethods class below:

```
public class ArrayMethods {
private int[] values;
public ArrayMethods(int[] initialValues) { values = initialValues; }

public void shiftRight() {.......}
public int returnSecondLargest {......}
```

- Shift all elements by one to the right and move the last element into the first position. For example, 1 4 9 16 25 would be transformed into 25 1 4 9 16
- Return the second-largest element in the array
- Remove the middle element if the array length is odd, or the middle two elements if the length is even

For the shifting method I have this:

```
public void shiftRight(){
    for(int i=0; i<=values.length-1; i++){
    if(i<values.length){
        values[i]=values[i+1];
    }
    else if(i==values.length+1){
        values[i]=values[0];
    } 
}
```

For the returning second largest method I have this:

```
public int returnSecondLargest(){
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {
        if(values[i] > values[i+1]){
        temp = values[i];
        values[i] =values[i + 1];
        values[i+1] = temp;
    }
    }
    return values[values.length - 2];
}
```

And for the removing middle element method I have this:

```
public void removeMiddleElement(){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++){
    count++;
    if(count%2==0){
        int middle1=count/2;
        int middle2=(count/2)+1;
        int[] copy = new int[values.length -1];
        System.arraycopy(copy, 0, copy, 0, middle1);
        System.arraycopy(copy, middle1+1, copy, middle1, copy.length-middle1-1);
        System.arraycopy(copy, 0, copy, 0, middle2);
        System.arraycopy(copy, middle2+1, copy, middle2, copy.length-middle2-1);
        copy = values; 
        }
    else if(count%2!=0){
        int middle3=(int) ((count/2)+.5);
        int[] copy = new int[values.length -1];
        System.arraycopy(copy, 0, copy, 0, middle3);
        System.arraycopy(copy, middle3+1, copy, middle3, copy.length-middle3-1);
        copy = values;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

In each of my methods I've gotten 'out of bounds' errors or they've just appeared to do nothing and return the original array with no changes made. If you see any glaring errors or have any advice it would be much appreciated :) Thanks!

edit: removeMiddleElement appears to do nothing, the other two methods give out of bounds errors at the line that says values[i+1]

Comment: Which method gives which problem

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: removemiddleelement does nothing, the other two produce out of bounds errors specifically where it says values[i +1]

Comment: good news I got secondLargest to work!! :) still struggling a bit with the others though

Comment: got shiftRight to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
for the array must be sorted
public void shiftRight(){
       int temp  = values[values.length -1];
       if(values.length >= 2)
       {
           System.arraycopy(values,0,values,1, values.length -1);
       }
       values[0] = temp;
    }
```

the second function (and also the array must be sorted)

```
public int returnSecondLargest()
    {
        return values[values.length - 2];
    }


public void removeMiddleElement()
    {
        int count = values.length ;
        int[] copy;
            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                int middle1 = count / 2;
                int middle2 = (count / 2);
                copy = new int[values.length - 2];
                System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, middle1 - 1);
                System.arraycopy(values, middle2 + 1 , copy, middle2 - 1, middle2 - 1);
            }
            else if (count % 2 != 0)
            {
                copy = new int[values.length - 1];
                int middle1 = count / 2;
                int middle2 = (count / 2);
                System.arraycopy(values, 0, copy, 0, middle1);
                System.arraycopy(values, middle2 +1, copy, middle2, (count / 2 ));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your shift right method, consider that you'll be starting at the max index value of your array. So rather than incrementing index (or i), you'll be decrementing from the end of the array! Since doing so, you'll have to store the value at the max index before you move things around, so dedicate an integer value that will be assigned to array[0] once the for loop exits!

ShiftRight Method

public static void shiftRight(int[] array) {

```
  int max = array[array.length - 1]; /*this value stores the max INDEX (not the value of the MAX index)*/

  /*- i starts at the index before the last index of the array
    - the for loop will exit once i is less than zero
    - keep in mind, we are working with the indexes and not the actual values */

  for (int i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
     array[i+1] = array[i]; /* takes the array value at the max index and replaces it with the array index before it */
  }   

  array[0] = max; /*setting the highest index to the first index of the array */
```

} //end shiftRight